# RDP fails when using Public IP to connect from LAN client

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, pfsense

The title pretty much says it. Here's the setup:

- host: Windows 11 Pro
- client: RD Client on iPhone
- WAN_IP: using Public DNS
- LAN_IP: using host's LAN static IP
- port forwards are configured properly on my pfSense router
- local DNS and DHCP are achieved using PiHole

When trying to RDP to WAN_IP from my phone while connected to LAN, connection fails with `Error 0x204`.
When trying to RDP to WAN_IP from my phone while connected to CELL, connection works as expected.
When trying to RDP to  LAN_IP from my phone while connected to LAN, connection works as expected.

No configuration changes were made between tests. The condition persists whether I use the DNS name for WAN_IP, or just manually entering the known WAN_IP.

Windows Event logs show the following on a successful connection:

```
Listener RDP-Tcp received a connection

Log Name: Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational
```

No log entry is generated when I try the WAN_IP connected to LAN.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be happening? It's not ideal for me to have 2 separate connection profiles for this host, but more I'm even more concerned with the principle of the matter. I cannot fathom why this would be happening and I would love to be educated as to why.

Comment: haha Just make sure to stop the port-forwarding and only enable that for a kind of VPN within your network. This is highly unsafe.

There are websites with the sole purpose of scanning every IP address in the world, trying to find open services. And when they're done, the start re-scanning everything again ( shodan is just an example )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common default behaviour for many networking equipment/configuration where LAN traffic to router's WAN IP do not follow the NAT rules/port forwarding so they fail.

The mitigation to this is called ***NAT Reflection*** which you can enable on your pfSense.

You can change the default system behaviour by changing the **NAT Reflection**  setting in the ***Network Address Translation*** section under *System* > *Advanced* on the *Firewall & NAT* tab. See more details (and it's worth a read to understand the options) in the documentation https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/nat/reflection.html

You can also set it on a per rule basis in the port forwarding rule itself by changing the **NAT Reflection** setting inside the rule setting. See https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/nat/port-forwards.html

Comment: You sir, nailed it right on the head. Immediately after toggling on `Enable automatic outbound NAT for Reflection` it started working properly. I don't know why I've never run into this issue before, but it works perfectly now. Thank you so much! If I remember to do it, I'm awarding you a bounty when this question becomes eligible.